# Find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{∞}\frac{x^n}{(1+x)(1+x^2)...(1+x^n)}$ For all $1 \le x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to calculate the sum of the following series for all $1 \le x$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{∞}\frac{x^n}{(1+x)(1+x^2)...(1+x^n)} $$

Ive been trying to calculate it for a couple hours now :/

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2837563/does-the-following-series-converge-uniformly-in-1-infty-sum-n-1-infty?noredirect=1

Comment: @metamorphy Yes It does. Thanks